# Xamarin.Forms Reference conflict

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

My problem in Xamarin.Forms

i tried to use the class Reachability.cs from Xamarin (Downloaded from official source) used the check a url or ip address is reachable.

When i try to build it shows me the following error message:

> Reference to type 'IPAddress' claims it is defined in 'System', but it
>   could not be found

I dont know how to solve it 
my usings are

```
using System;
using SystemConfiguration;
using CoreFoundation;
```

[image]

Kind Regards,

Stefan

Comment: What was the official source you got this from. I wasn't aware Xamarin had a downloads location so I'm kinda curious to see what else they have.

Comment: Nevermind found it I assume your refering to:https://github.com/xamarin/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reachability.cs depends on System.Net classes which do not exist in PCL.  To test Reachability in Forms, use the [Connectivity](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.Connectivity) plugin instead.

Comment: Only thing is how to use Task<bool> IsReachable(string host, int msTimeout = 5000); and get a boolean result back ?

Comment: private static async Task<bool> Ping(string Url)
        {
            var Task = await CrossConnectivity.Current.IsReachable(Url);

            return Task;

        }

Comment: Whats my boolean result than ?

Comment: bool result = await IsReachabel(url);

Answer (score 1):

IPAddress is part of System.Net
add

```
using System.Net;
```

to your usings - it' not listet in your question

Check that the following assemblies are selected in your references (right click on references, edit references, all - I hope the names are correct as my xamarin studio is in german)

- System
- System.Core
- System.Xml
- System.iOS

Add the reachability.cs to your project

Add this lines to the c'tor or somewhere else in the class you want to use the reachability stuff

```
UpdateStatus (null, null);
Reachability.ReachabilityChanged += UpdateStatus;
```

Add an eventhandler

```
void UpdateStatus (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Reachability.RemoteHostStatus ().ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(Reachability.InternetConnectionStatus ().ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(Reachability.LocalWifiConnectionStatus ().ToString());

    }
```

Comment: Mate everything else is working fine even Vibrate functions etc.

Comment: go to references and double click on system - check if system.net is available.

Comment: Still not working if i try to add the reference to VS2015 its says they woud be added at compile time ?